# Calculate the distribution of values in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to calculate the distribution of values from a large data set. The values are FLOATs between 1 and 7, and I'd like to aggregate them up to a certain granularity. Right now I'm aggregating to half values (1.0, 1.5, 2.0, etc) but I'd like to be able to set the granularity more dynamically (For example to one decimal). Is there a smart way of doing this? Right now I do this

```
    //create distribution table
$distribution_table="CREATE TABLE distribution_table(Collective_ability FLOAT Primary Key, Number INT)";

// Execute query
if (mysql_query($distribution_table))
  {
  echo "Table distribution_table created successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating distribution table: " . mysql_error();
  die;
  }


//Calculate distribution of Collective Ability
$distribution = "INSERT INTO distribution_table (Collective_ability) Values (1.0),(1.5),(2.0),(2.5),(3.0),(3.5),(4.0),(4.5),(5.0),(5.5),(6.0),(6.5),(7.0)";

// Execute query
if (mysql_query($distribution))
  {
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error Selecting Inserting values into distribution table: " . mysql_error();
  die;
  }

$number_of_1 = "UPDATE distribution_table SET Number = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CollectiveAbility > 0.75 AND CollectiveAbility < 1.25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM collective_ability) WHERE Collective_ability = 1.0";
$number_of_1_5 = "UPDATE distribution_table SET Number = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CollectiveAbility > 1.25 AND CollectiveAbility < 1.75 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM collective_ability) WHERE Collective_ability = 1.5";
$number_of_2 = "UPDATE distribution_table SET Number = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CollectiveAbility > 1.75 AND CollectiveAbility < 2.25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM collective_ability) WHERE Collective_ability = 2.0";
$number_of_2_5 = "UPDATE distribution_table SET Number = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CollectiveAbility > 2.25 AND CollectiveAbility < 2.75 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM collective_ability) WHERE Collective_ability = 2.5";
$number_of_3 = "UPDATE distribution_table SET Number = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CollectiveAbility > 2.75 AND CollectiveAbility < 3.25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM collective_ability) WHERE Collective_ability = 3.0";
$number_of_3_5 = "UPDATE distribution_table SET Number = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CollectiveAbility > 3.25 AND CollectiveAbility < 3.75 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM collective_ability) WHERE Collective_ability = 3.5";
$number_of_4 = "UPDATE distribution_table SET Number = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CollectiveAbility > 3.75 AND CollectiveAbility < 4.25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM collective_ability) WHERE Collective_ability = 4.0";
$number_of_4_5 = "UPDATE distribution_table SET Number = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CollectiveAbility > 4.25 AND CollectiveAbility < 4.75 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM collective_ability) WHERE Collective_ability = 4.5";
$number_of_5 = "UPDATE distribution_table SET Number = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CollectiveAbility > 4.75 AND CollectiveAbility < 5.25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM collective_ability) WHERE Collective_ability = 5.0";
$number_of_5_5 = "UPDATE distribution_table SET Number = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CollectiveAbility > 5.25 AND CollectiveAbility < 5.75 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM collective_ability) WHERE Collective_ability = 5.5";
$number_of_6 = "UPDATE distribution_table SET Number = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CollectiveAbility > 5.75 AND CollectiveAbility < 6.25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM collective_ability) WHERE Collective_ability = 6.0";
$number_of_6_5 = "UPDATE distribution_table SET Number = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CollectiveAbility > 6.25 AND CollectiveAbility < 6.75 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM collective_ability) WHERE Collective_ability = 6.5";
$number_of_7 = "UPDATE distribution_table SET Number = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CollectiveAbility > 6.75 AND CollectiveAbility < 7.25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM collective_ability) WHERE Collective_ability = 7.0";

// Execute query
if (mysql_query($number_of_1))
  {
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error entering number count: " . mysql_error();
  die;
  }

// Execute query
if (mysql_query($number_of_1_5))
  {
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error entering number count: " . mysql_error();
  die;
  }

  // Execute query
if (mysql_query($number_of_2))
  {
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error entering number count: " . mysql_error();
  die;
  }

  // Execute query
if (mysql_query($number_of_2_5))
  {
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error entering number count: " . mysql_error();
  die;
  }

  // Execute query
if (mysql_query($number_of_3))
  {
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error entering number count: " . mysql_error();
  die;
  }
  // Execute query
if (mysql_query($number_of_3_5))
  {
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error entering number count: " . mysql_error();
  die;
  }
  // Execute query
if (mysql_query($number_of_4))
  {
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error entering number count: " . mysql_error();
  die;
  }
  // Execute query
if (mysql_query($number_of_4_5))
  {
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error entering number count: " . mysql_error();
  die;
  }
  // Execute query
if (mysql_query($number_of_5))
  {
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error entering number count: " . mysql_error();
  die;
  }
  // Execute query
if (mysql_query($number_of_5_5))
  {
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error entering number count: " . mysql_error();
  die;
  }
  // Execute query
if (mysql_query($number_of_6))
  {
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error entering number count: " . mysql_error();
  die;
  }
  // Execute query
if (mysql_query($number_of_6_5))
  {
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error entering number count: " . mysql_error();
  die;
  }
  // Execute query
if (mysql_query($number_of_7))
  {
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error entering number count: " . mysql_error();
  die;
  }
```

Comment: use a `for` loop. Your current setup is start at 1 end at 7 and step 0.5 - new setup would just need to change the step to 0.1

Comment: Your sql also uses -0.25 to +0.25. these would also need to change according to the step (0.5xstep)

Comment: can I do a `for`loop for the INSERT INTO call as well?

Comment: Yes. But running several queries is a bit slower that using a script to build the one long query like the one you already have. ie `$sql='INSERT INTO distribution_table (Collective_ability) Values (1.0)'; for($loop=1.5;$loop<=7;$loop+=0.5) {  $sql.=',('.$loop.')'; }`